# SQL Count Distinct Colums and Return all rows

Tags: sql, mysql, select, count, group

I have table in MySQL and I am trying to filter the data from ColA and count the instances of a result in ColB while still getting all matching rows

TABLE Name: CityCityStuff

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CityA | CityB | Other Stuff |
| CityA | CityC | Other Stuff |
| CityB | CityC | Other Stuff |
| CityB | CityA | Other Stuff |
| CityB | CityA | Other Stuff |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff |
| CityC | CityB | Other Stuff |
| CityC | CityD | Other Stuff |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff |

I want to know:

```
SELECT * FROM CityCityStuff WHERE ColA = 'CityC'
```

And then how many times each ColB is repeated while still getting all rows where ColA = CityC

Results returned look like:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | TotalEach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityB | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityD | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff | 2 |

OR:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | TotalEach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff |  |
| CityC | CityB | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityD | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff |  |

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Many will have a `windows function` to solve this.

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Version 8 will support windows functions.

Comment: It is a hosting account but I believe:

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.15

Comment: Server version: 10.6.16-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

-

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.15

Comment: That's not MySQL, but same answer applies to both. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt  [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7vzCxJW3BhQ1t7Twv24KBt/0)

Tested in MySql v5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 8.0

```
CREATE TABLE CityCityStuff 
(
    ColA    VARCHAR(512),
    ColB    VARCHAR(512),
    ColC    VARCHAR(512)

);

INSERT INTO CityCityStuff (ColA , ColB , ColC ) VALUES
    ('CityA ', 'CityB ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityA ', 'CityC ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityB ', 'CityC ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityB ', 'CityA ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityB ', 'CityA ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityC ', 'CityA ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityC ', 'CityA ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityC ', 'CityB ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityC ', 'CityD ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityC ', 'CityE ', 'Other Stuff'),
    ('CityC ', 'CityE ', 'Other Stuff')

Select * from CityCityStuff;

Select cola, colb, colc, (Select count(*) as TotalEach from CityCityStuff a Where a.ColB=b.ColB and cola='cityC') as TotalEach
from CityCityStuff b
where cola='cityC'
```

| colA | colB | colC | TotalEach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityB | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityD | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff | 2 |

Comment: This also worked and is compatible with more DBs!!  Thank yo also!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `count()` windows function in MariaDB (and MySQL 8 and other DBMS). The `partition by colA, colB` essentially groups your data when counting.

```
select 
  colA, 
  colB, 
  colC, 
  count(*) over (partition by colA, colB) as totalEach
from citycitystuff
where colA = 'CityC'
```

| colA | colB | colC | totalEach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityA | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityB | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityD | Other Stuff | 1 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff | 2 |
| CityC | CityE | Other Stuff | 2 |

[fiddle found here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PlwEr2rN)